# Same data and query. One finishes in seconds; the other times out

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm using AWS RDS Postgres v13.7

I have a table, foo, of ~1m rows.  I run a query that's a select distinct on 2 columns in a CTE, a self join after, and finally a select count(*).

I clone the using `create table bar as (select * from foo)`.  I run the same query on this table.

The query using foo hangs and never finishes.  The query using bar finishes in 10 seconds.  I'm running/starting them side by side and tried running one before the other so it's not a resource or order of query issue; foo never finishes, bar always finishes in a few seconds.  There is a period of time in the afternoon when the foo query does also finish quickly so there may be a timing thing.

Literally the same data and query with different outcomes.

I've done a vacuum.  Explain on the 2 tables and queries are identical.

When I try to decompose the CTE, the select distinct on foo or bar perform the same, as expected.  It's the self join on foo that hangs.

I've already read [the post "Identical tables, identical query, completely different execution times"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135652/identical-tables-identical-query-completely-different-execution-times) and [Exactly same query and plan but different duration and total reads. I Know parameter sniffing but](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/256967/exactly-same-query-and-plan-but-different-duration-and-total-reads-i-know-param) and I don't believe they apply to my situation

My expectation is the foo query should run as fast as the bar query or they behave the same way

Comment: Please add the execution plans. Look on `pg_stat_activity` if the query that takes long is stuck behind a lock (`wait_event`).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with skewed stats for `foo`.
A query execution plan devised by Postgres relies on query semantics, indices available, server configuration, etc., BUT it also relies on table stats that postgres has gathered about your data (see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-stats.html). Ultimately, a query plan is devised based on heuristics.

I am guessing for your case it could be that `foo` might have been present for longer period of time and then its collected stats are different than the `bar` ones, and `bar` stats cause query planner to devise a better query plan which does not timeout.

One thing you can do is to try to create something like `bar2` and confirm that one also works and see if you can compare query execution plans for `foo`, `bar`, and `bar2`. Likely foo would be different than either `bar` or `bar2`. Also, `bar` and `bar2` should roughly be the same.

I hope this helps a bit.

**EDIT**: as pointed out by another answer - if the above proves to be true - you can do the: `VACUUM ANALYZE foo;` to refresh the stats.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL, VACUUM reclaims storage occupied by dead tuples and ANALYZE updates the statistics, or use VACUUM ANALYZE to reclaims storage and update table statistics.

e.g:

```
VACUUM ANALYZE foo;
-- now run your query
```